# Android MediaPlayer resume/pause buffering stream

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm using android MediaPlayer to stream music/podcast from Internet.

What I would like to do is to manage the buffering stream to not start automatically and to resume/pause it when I want but it seems that this is not possible.

Here's some basic instructions.

```
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(streamUrl);
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

at this point `prepareAsync` initialize the mediaPlayer and start buffering.

After it start buffering the play/pause actions will only pause the audio but not the buffer and it seems that there's no exposed method in MediaPlayer to do so (but I know that internally it's doing that).

I think that maybe, the only solution (if there's no methods) is to give to mediaplayer a temp file to play and I manage to buffer the downloaded audio in that file.

What do you think?

Comment: If you don't need seek functionality, you can use a named pipe. A regular file won't work unless you wait until it's entirely downloaded before setting it as the data source. Outside of that, you can use a local proxy server, although implementing full functionality for a player gets a bit tricky.

Comment: I was already thinking about this solution but I was worried about taking care of all buffering/fail situation. And now I added the seek problem that I totally forgot :D